# mysql - Delete keyword with link from wordpress post database

Tags: mysql

Thanks in advance for the help.

I want to remove some stuffed keyword with link from my wordpress post table example of link `<a href="http://example.com/keyword/">keyword</a>`

I have some posts since 2011 and it`s quite hard to edit all those posts to remove the links....

Any help will be most welcome

Regards

Daniel

Comment: What does the output string look like?

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer. And you might try the [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin, but back up your site first.

Comment: Can i use this : UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, '<a href="http://example.com/keyword/">keyword</a>', '' ) ;  To find <a href="http://example.com/keyword/">keyword</a> and replace with empty space ""